# removing dataseries both by clicking on datapoints or checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Can someone show me how to combine the following 2 solutions into 1 html page. Toggling dataseries both via check box or clicking on datapoints as shown on the following 2 links:

1)
http://jsfiddle.net/X2q69/1/

```
$(".chart").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        var label = item.series.label;
        $([plot1, plot2]).each(function(i,plotObj){
            var someData = plotObj.getData();
            for (var i=0; i<someData.length; i++){
                if (someData[i].label == label){
                    someData.splice(i,1);
                }                
            }
            plotObj.setData(someData);
            plotObj.setupGrid();
            plotObj.draw();                
        });
    }        
});
```

2)
    http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/GVt9V/1/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/95DHZ/ and what was the problem you were facing in combining them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/x5EYx/).  I modified the 2nd link from filtering the data to toggling the `series.lines.show` option.  I think this is a cleaner approach.  It uses the below function from either the checkbox or the `plotclick` handler, toggles the show and redraws the plot.

```
toggleSeries = function(label){
    var someData = somePlot.getData();
    for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++){
        if (someData[i].label == label){
            someData[i].lines.show = !someData[i].lines.show;
            break;
        }
    }
    somePlot.setData(someData);
    somePlot.setupGrid();
    somePlot.draw();
}
```